# how can i change orientation of a notification banner?

Tags: java, notifications

i have a problem with the DS Desktop Notify library
in this library, all of notify banners has left to right orientation
i want to change the direction of these notifies from LTR to RTL
(the icons most be in the right side of the banner, also title and message need to start from right side of the banner
how can i do this in this library?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMlEI.png "screenshot"

i have tried using the "applyComponentOrientation" for the frame, but it's not working

```
    private static class DesktopLayoutFrame extends JDialog {
    Image bg;
    boolean nativeTrans;

    boolean finished=true;
    boolean clicked=false;

    public DesktopLayoutFrame() {
        super((JFrame)null,"DesktopLayoutFrame");
        setUndecorated(true);
        nativeTrans=Utils.isTranslucencySupported();
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,nativeTrans? 0:255));
        setContentPane(new JComponent(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                render((Graphics2D)g);
            }
        });
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
                clicked=true;
            }
        });
        setFocusableWindowState(false);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        System.out.println("Desktop Notify Frame deployed.");
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        boolean bool=isVisible();
        if (visible) {
            Rectangle screenSize = Utils.getScreenSize();
            setBounds(screenSize.x+screenSize.width-310, screenSize.y,
                      305, screenSize.height-5);
            if (!bool && !nativeTrans)
                bg=Utils.getBackgroundCap(getBounds());
        }
        super.setVisible(visible);
    }

    /**
     * Paints the window contents.
     * @param rd a graphics2D object received from the original paint event.
     */
    public void render(Graphics2D rd) {
        Point p = getMousePosition();
        finished = false;
        int x = 0, y = getHeight();
        long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (windows.isEmpty()) finished = true;
        int cur = Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR;
        if (!nativeTrans) rd.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);
        for (int i = 0; i < windows.size(); i++) {
            DesktopNotify window = windows.get(i);
            if (window.isVisible()) {
                y -= window.h;
                if (window.popupStart == 0) {
                    window.popupStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                if (y > 0) {
                    boolean hover = false;
                    if (p != null) {
                        if (p.y > y && p.y < y + window.h) {
                            hover = true;
                            if (window.getAction() != null) {
                                cur = Cursor.HAND_CURSOR;
                            }
                            if (clicked) {
                                if (window.getAction() != null) {
                                    final DesktopNotify w = window;
                                    final long lf = l;
                                    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){@Override public void run(){
                                        w.getAction().actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(w, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "fireAction", lf, 0));
                                    }});
                                }
                                if (window.expTime() == Long.MAX_VALUE) {
                                    window.timeOut = l - window.popupStart + 500;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    window.render(x, y, hover, rd, l);
                    if (window.markedForHide) {
                        window.timeOut = l - window.popupStart + 500;
                        window.markedForHide = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    window.popupStart = l;
                }
                if (l > window.expTime() || (y <= 0 && window.markedForHide)) {
                    window.markedForHide = false;
                    window.setVisible(false);
                    windows.remove(window);
                    i--;
                }
                y -= 5;
            }
        }
        clicked = false;
        setCursor(new Cursor(cur));
    }
}
```

i think above code in "DesktopNotifyDriver.java" has to be edited for this. sorry for my english
Please Help Me Through This

Comment: If you mean this [DS Desktop Notify](https://dscore.webcindario.com/software/desktopnotify.php) library, then I see that you can also download the source code. There may be something in the API that allows you to change the orientation. Have you tried looking through the source code?

Comment: yes i have, actually i can't see where is the exact part of these problem. these library renders the strings for title and message. it has not a layout manager, or jcomponent (like jlabel or jpanel) for using Swing or awt Orientation.

Comment: Looks to me that you didn't post your code. You posted part of the library code. If you need to modify the library's code, why not implement the required functionality yourself? Looks like all you want is to display an undecorated `JDialog` that contains a `JLabel`.

Comment: exactly, this is part of the source of this library. actually this is the part that i think needs to be edited. i don't know how to implement these functionality. these library works perfect (in left to right direction). all i want is changing the orientation of these notify banner

Comment: See this line of the code you posted: `rd.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);` I guess the image being drawn is the icon. If my guess is right and you want the icon drawn on the right side, then you need to change the coordinates from (0, 0) because (0, 0) means the icon's top left corner lies on the top left corner of the `JDialog`. That would mean you have to calculate the x and y coordinates that would paint the icon on the right side. Looks like the owner of this library didn't make it I18N compatible. I still think it would be easier to write your own popup notification window.

Comment: thanks for your help. yes it's absolutely right and i have fixed the icon position. the main problem is title and message. actually when i edit the start position of titile or message, again it shows them from left to right (out) of screen. something like this image: https://i.imgur.com/54fA4Xw.jpg "screen"
anyways this was my first question in stackoverflow and @Abra you helped me a lot. thank you man